# slimbox with fasthover slideshow

Tags: performance, hover, slider, slimbox

I'm trying to put together slimbox and fasthover slideshow. Here's my Html code:

```
<section>
            <div class="hs-wrapper">
                <a href="images/75.jpg" rel="lightbox02" title="budownictwo1"><img src="images/75.jpg" alt="image01" style="height:326.5px;width:518px;float:left;"></img></a>
                <a href="images/portfolio1.jpg" rel="lightbox02" title="budownictwo2"><img src="images/portfolio1.jpg" style="height:326.5px;width:518px;float:left;" alt="image02"></img></a>
                <a href="images/boxPozycjonowanieBG.jpg" rel="lightbox02" title="budownictwo1"><img src="images/boxPozycjonowanieBG.jpg" style="height:326.5px;width:518px;float:left;" alt="image03"></img></a>

            </div>
        </section>
```

My css:

```
    .hs-wrapper{
    width: 518px;
    height: 326.5px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    float:left;
}
.hs-wrapper img a{
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-animation: showMe 0.8s linear infinite 0s forwards;
    -moz-animation: showMe 0.8s linear infinite 0s forwards;
    -o-animation: showMe 0.8s linear infinite 0s forwards;
    -ms-animation: showMe 0.8s linear infinite 0s forwards;
    animation: showMe 0.8s linear infinite 0s forwards;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
    -o-animation-play-state: paused;
    -ms-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused;   
}
.hs-wrapper  img a:nth-child(1){
    z-index: 9;
}
.hs-wrapper img a:nth-child(2){
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.1s;
    -o-animation-delay: 0.1s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 0.1s;
    animation-delay: 0.1s;
    z-index: 8;
}
.hs-wrapper img a:nth-child(3){
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.2s;
    -o-animation-delay: 0.2s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 0.2s;
    animation-delay: 0.2s;
    z-index: 7;
}
.hs-wrapper img a:nth-child(4){
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.3s;
    -o-animation-delay: 0.3s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 0.3s;
    animation-delay: 0.3s;
    z-index: 6;
}
.hs-wrapper img a:nth-child(5){
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.4s;
    -o-animation-delay: 0.4s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 0.4s;
    animation-delay: 0.4s;
    z-index: 5;
}
.hs-wrapper img a:nth-child(6){
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.5s;
    -o-animation-delay: 0.5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 0.5s;
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
    z-index: 4;
}
.hs-wrapper img a:nth-child(7){
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.6s;
    -o-animation-delay: 0.6s;
    -ms-nimation-delay: 0.6s;
    animation-delay: 0.6s;
    z-index: 3;
}
.hs-wrapper img a:nth-child(8){
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.7s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.7s;
    -o-animation-delay: 0.7s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 0.7s;
    animation-delay: 0.7s;
    z-index: 2;
}
.hs-wrapper:hover img a{
    -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
    -moz-animation-play-state: running;
    -o-animation-play-state: running;
    -ms-animation-play-state: running;
    animation-play-state: running;
}
.hs-overlay{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 500;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.3) inset;
    pointer-events: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
.hs-overlay span{
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 293px;
    left: 20px;
    top: 200px;
    color: #fff;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 38px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    text-align: center;
    pointer-events: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.hs-wrapper:hover .hs-overlay{
    opacity: 1;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.3) inset;
}

@-webkit-keyframes showMe {
    0% { visibility: visible; z-index: 100; }
    12.5% { visibility: visible; z-index: 100; }
    25% { visibility: hidden; z-index: 0; }
    100% { visibility: hidden; z-index: 0; }
}

@-moz-keyframes showMe {
    0% { visibility: visible; z-index: 100; }
    12.5% { visibility: visible; z-index: 100; }
    25% { visibility: hidden; z-index: 0; }
    100% { visibility: hidden; z-index: 0; }
}

@-o-keyframes showMe {
    0% { visibility: visible; z-index: 100; }
    12.5% { visibility: visible; z-index: 100; }
    25% { visibility: hidden; z-index: 0; }
    100% { visibility: hidden; z-index: 0; }
}

@-ms-keyframes showMe {
    0% { visibility: visible; z-index: 100; }
    12.5% { visibility: visible; z-index: 100; }
    25% { visibility: hidden; z-index: 0; }
    100% { visibility: hidden; z-index: 0; }
}

@keyframes showMe {
    0% { visibility: visible; z-index: 100; }
    12.5% { visibility: visible; z-index: 100; }
    25% { visibility: hidden; z-index: 0; }
    100% { visibility: hidden; z-index: 0; }
}
```

My js:

```
    (function(w){var E=w(window),u,f,F=-1,n,x,D,v,y,L,r,m=!window.XMLHttpRequest,s=[],l=document.documentElement,k={},t=new Image(),J=new Image(),H,a,g,p,I,d,G,c,A,K;w(function(){w("body").append(w([H=w('<div id="lbOverlay" />').click(C)[0],a=w('<div id="lbCenter" />')[0],G=w('<div id="lbBottomContainer" />')[0]]).css("display","none"));g=w('<div id="lbImage" />').appendTo(a).append(p=w('<div style="position: relative;" />').append([I=w('<a id="lbPrevLink" href="#" />').click(B)[0],d=w('<a id="lbNextLink" href="#" />').click(e)[0]])[0])[0];c=w('<div id="lbBottom" />').appendTo(G).append([w('<a id="lbCloseLink" href="#" />').click(C)[0],A=w('<div id="lbCaption" />')[0],K=w('<div id="lbNumber" />')[0],w('<div style="clear: both;" />')[0]])[0]});w.slimbox=function(O,N,M){u=w.extend({loop:false,overlayOpacity:0.8,overlayFadeDuration:400,resizeDuration:400,resizeEasing:"swing",initialWidth:250,initialHeight:250,imageFadeDuration:400,captionAnimationDuration:400,counterText:"Image {x} of {y}",closeKeys:[27,88,67],previousKeys:[37,80],nextKeys:[39,78]},M);if(typeof O=="string"){O=[[O,N]];N=0}y=E.scrollTop()+(E.height()/2);L=u.initialWidth;r=u.initialHeight;w(a).css({top:Math.max(0,y-(r/2)),width:L,height:r,marginLeft:-L/2}).show();v=m||(H.currentStyle&&(H.currentStyle.position!="fixed"));if(v){H.style.position="absolute"}w(H).css("opacity",u.overlayOpacity).fadeIn(u.overlayFadeDuration);z();j(1);f=O;u.loop=u.loop&&(f.length>1);return b(N)};w.fn.slimbox=function(M,P,O){P=P||function(Q){return[Q.href,Q.title]};O=O||function(){return true};var N=this;return N.unbind("click").click(function(){var S=this,U=0,T,Q=0,R;T=w.grep(N,function(W,V){return O.call(S,W,V)});for(R=T.length;Q<R;++Q){if(T[Q]==S){U=Q}T[Q]=P(T[Q],Q)}return w.slimbox(T,U,M)})};function z(){var N=E.scrollLeft(),M=E.width();w([a,G]).css("left",N+(M/2));if(v){w(H).css({left:N,top:E.scrollTop(),width:M,height:E.height()})}}function j(M){if(M){w("object").add(m?"select":"embed").each(function(O,P){s[O]=[P,P.style.visibility];P.style.visibility="hidden"})}else{w.each(s,function(O,P){P[0].style.visibility=P[1]});s=[]}var N=M?"bind":"unbind";E[N]("scroll resize",z);w(document)[N]("keydown",o)}function o(O){var N=O.which,M=w.inArray;return(M(N,u.closeKeys)>=0)?C():(M(N,u.nextKeys)>=0)?e():(M(N,u.previousKeys)>=0)?B():null}function B(){return b(x)}function e(){return b(D)}function b(M){if(M>=0){F=M;n=f[F][0];x=(F||(u.loop?f.length:0))-1;D=((F+1)%f.length)||(u.loop?0:-1);q();a.className="lbLoading";k=new Image();k.onload=i;k.src=n}return false}function i(){a.className="";w(g).css({backgroundImage:"url("+n+")",visibility:"hidden",display:""});w(p).width(k.width);w([p,I,d]).height(k.height);w(A).html(f[F][1]||"");w(K).html((((f.length>1)&&u.counterText)||"").replace(/{x}/,F+1).replace(/{y}/,f.length));if(x>=0){t.src=f[x][0]}if(D>=0){J.src=f[D][0]}L=g.offsetWidth;r=g.offsetHeight;var M=Math.max(0,y-(r/2));if(a.offsetHeight!=r){w(a).animate({height:r,top:M},u.resizeDuration,u.resizeEasing)}if(a.offsetWidth!=L){w(a).animate({width:L,marginLeft:-L/2},u.resizeDuration,u.resizeEasing)}w(a).queue(function(){w(G).css({width:L,top:M+r,marginLeft:-L/2,visibility:"hidden",display:""});w(g).css({display:"none",visibility:"",opacity:""}).fadeIn(u.imageFadeDuration,h)})}function h(){if(x>=0){w(I).show()}if(D>=0){w(d).show()}w(c).css("marginTop",-c.offsetHeight).animate({marginTop:0},u.captionAnimationDuration);G.style.visibility=""}function q(){k.onload=null;k.src=t.src=J.src=n;w([a,g,c]).stop(true);w([I,d,g,G]).hide()}function C(){if(F>=0){q();F=x=D=-1;w(a).hide();w(H).stop().fadeOut(u.overlayFadeDuration,j)}return false}})(jQuery);

// AUTOLOAD CODE BLOCK (MAY BE CHANGED OR REMOVED)
if (!/android|iphone|ipod|series60|symbian|windows ce|blackberry/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    jQuery(function($) {
        $("a[rel^='lightbox']").slimbox({/* Put custom options here */}, null, function(el) {
            return (this == el) || ((this.rel.length > 8) && (this.rel == el.rel));
        });
    });
}
```

All I get is either flickering image or the slider stops work and only slimbox works. Please help me put the 2 together.

Comment: Can you provide a live example I can test from?

Comment: http://www.ewelinawoloszyn.com/videomockup/realizacje2.html

Comment: Do you want the image to continuously change as your hover over it? It's working on this page, http://www.ewelinawoloszyn.com/videomockup/realizacje.html. Where should I click to open the lightbox?

Comment: I want images to scroll infinitely but also the lightbox to work as you click at each image. At realizacje html only scroll works on realizacje2 only lightbox works.I want both to work at once.

Comment: Okay. Is this the image you click on while it's changing really fast? Kindof like a lucky pick thing, where the corresponding image will display on the lightbox? Or is it when you click on the box, you are shown a lightbox of the images changing in the area you hover over?

Comment: After clicking it displays it as first image and the following images after seckond click. It works like that already on realizacje2. I'll slow down the animation.